# How do I add a sprite at an angle in swift?

Tags: swift

Im creating a game and I have a line that I want to add at different angles for different scenarios. For now, lets assume that I want to place it at 3 different angles, 45 degrees, 90 degrees, and 135 degrees. In my png file, I've created the line at 90 degrees (vertical). Is there any way I can add this line at these different angles by default or do I need to create 2 more png files for the other 2 lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create 2 more different files.

For this you need to set the `anchorPoint` of the sprite so that rotation and placement becomes easy for you. In your case you would need to set `anchorPoint` as (0,0). [Anchor Point Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Sprites/Sprites.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH9-SW36)

Then you can just set `zRotation` property which would rotate the sprite.